# Scope function in JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to access the function inside my function:

```
var initSlides = function () {

  var setMenuActive = function (slideId) { console.log(slideId) }
}
```

I would like to do something like:

`initSlides.setMenuActive(0)`

I've tried this way:

```
var initSlides = function () {

    var setMenuActive = function (slideId) { console.log(slideId) }

    return { setMenuActive: setMenuActive }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to do something like

`initSlides.setMenuActive(0);`

then you're going to need an object with a method named setMenuActive..

```
var initSlides = {
    setMenuActive: function(slideId) {
       console.log(slideId);
    }
};
```

I haven't tried your code, but I believe you would use yours along these lines..

```
var initSlides = function () {

    var setMenuActive = function (slideId) { console.log(slideId) }

    return { setMenuActive: setMenuActive }
}

var captureTheReturnedObject = initSlides();
captureTheReturnedObject.setMenuActive(0);
```

I've given it an awful name to make a point :)

Comment: initSlides... in your code returns an object that has the function you want... so you need to call initSlides and capture it in a variable and then, call the method on that captured object